# Как получить целое число?

Tags: c, алгоритм

Даны два символа `ch1` и `ch2`. Получить целое число `a`, последовательность нечётных битов которого представляет собой код `ch1`, а последовательность чётных – код `ch2`.

У меня есть мысль, в цикле "пока" `ch1!=0` и `ch2!=0` делать аккуратно побитовое смещение `ch1`, то что откинулось с помощью побитового "или" вставлять в конец `a`, такая же процедура для `ch2`, и повтор цикла. Мысль плоха тем, что результат будет задом наоборот.

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно это всё сделать?

Comment: Идея совершенно правильная, просто надо либо брать, либо вставлять с другого конца.

Comment: @AnT это понятно, но не понятно как с другой стороны вставлять ;(

Comment: Есть и более остроумные решения: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#Interleave64bitOps

Comment: @AnT оёёй а куда смотреть? ))

Comment: `x |= (1 << i)` для 32-бит `int x` ровнехонько сделает i-й бит в x единичкой

Comment: @avp what is it ? )

Comment: Это как установить i-й бит в числе. Разве проблема не в этом? `for (i = 0; сh1 || ch2; i++, ch1 >>= 1, ch2 >>= 1) { if (ch1 & 1) x |= (1 << (i * 2)); if (ch2 & 1) x |= (1 << (i * 2 + 1)); }` Только символы не забудьте сделать `unsigned char`

Comment: Автор, идея понятна? (`x` это результат)

Comment: Вот и я подумал про умножение, зачем вообще циклы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решить задачу можно множеством разных способов. Например, практически лобовое решение

```
unsigned result = 0;
for (unsigned mask = 1; ch1 != 0 || ch2 != 0; ch1 >>= 1, ch2 >>= 1, mask <<= 2)
  result |= (ch2 & 1) * mask | (ch1 & 1) * (mask << 1);
```

или может даже лучше

```
unsigned result = 0;
for (unsigned shift = 0; ch1 != 0 || ch2 != 0; ch1 >>= 1, ch2 >>= 1, shift += 2)
  result |= ((ch2 & 1) + (ch1 & 1) * 2) << shift;
```

Позаботьтесь только о том, чтобы `ch1` и `сh2` имели  беззнаковый тип (или хотя бы изначально имели положительные значения).

При желании, к такому алгоритму можно "подмешать" использование заранее вычисленных табличных результатов. Чем больше размер таблицы, тем меньше итераций придется делать циклу. Соотношение ингредиентов в этой смеси, т.е. выбор размера таблицы - дело вашего вкуса. Например, с таблицей размера 16 (для всех 4-битовых комбинаций) получается так

```
static const unsigned TABLE16[] = 
{ 
  0x00, 0x01, 0x04, 0x05, 0x10, 0x11, 0x14, 0x15, 
  0x40, 0x41, 0x44, 0x45, 0x50, 0x51, 0x54, 0x55 
};

unsigned result = 0;
for (unsigned shift = 0; ch1 != 0 || ch2 != 0; ch1 >>= 4, ch2 >>= 4, shift += 8)
  result |= (TABLE16[ch1 & 0xF] * 2 + TABLE16[ch2 & 0xF]) << shift;
```

Если ваши исходные значения имеют ширину 8 битов и вы не поленитесь подготовить таблицу размера 256, то можно будет обойтись вообще без цикла

```
result = TABLE256[ch1] * 2 + TABLE256[ch2];
```

хотя для 8-битного входа и с таблицей `TABLE16` цикл делает всего две итерации, которые легко развернуть.

Comment: Да, второй вариант хорош. Очень быстрый, отлично ложится на суперскалярную архитектуру и будет замечательно заполнять конвейер